# How to convert the Char * to hexadecimal value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, char, hex

I have a char array that i need to convert to hexadecimal value

```
char* arrrr =[self mountLVparams:NULL :c :code_ward_arr];  

int size =strlen(arrrr);
```

I am trying with this but this not happening

```
 NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:arrrr length:sizeof(sizeof(unsigned char)*size)];
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to convert to a hexadecimal string like "0xfeed"?

Comment: Can you give examples of your desired input and output?  I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: see i am using mount method when i return it contains arrrr value that is Emudhra¿services¿¿¿ okay if want that to convert to hexadecimal value

Comment: code is fine check char* arrrr has value

Comment: i resolved the issue `NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:arrrr length:size];
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *inp = [NSString stringWithString:@"MmMmMm"];
char star = [inp characterAtIndex:3];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"char:%c andHex:%x",[inp characterAtIndex:3],star];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
```

Look at in output is `"%@"` as a regular string. In string you will receive hex value of char.

```
char:m andHex:6d
```

With array you will have to do it in a loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't "convert" a value to hexadecimal. Hexadecimal is just a different way of counting or displaying the same numbers.

```
if (0xFF==255)
{
  NSLog(@"255 equals 0xFF");
}
```

Now see the following code below which will convert your byte array into and int, then display then format the int as a hex string.

```
-(void) convertData: (unsigned char*) data 
{
   int numBytes = sizeof(int);

   //convert array of bytes to NSData*
   NSData* binaryData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: (void*) data length: numBytes];

   //read value of number stored in data, presuming it is an integer
   int number =  *((int*) data);

   //format number as a hex string
   NSString* hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X",number];
}
```